# PHPExcel download excel file

Tags: php, encoding, download, import-from-excel

have a problem to download excel file. When im saving on server its worked ok. But when i try to download things goes wrong

```
enter code hererequire_once('Classes/PHPExcel.php');

    $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp; 

    $cacheSettings = array( ' memoryCacheSize ' => '1024MB'); 

    ini_set("memory_limit","-1");

    ini_set('max_execution_time', 13600); 

    PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings); 

    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    // Set document properties
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Techizer")

                                 ->setLastModifiedBy("Techizer")

                                 ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")

                                 ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")

                                 ->setCategory("Test result file");


    if($file=="employer")

    {

        // Rename worksheet

        $file = 'employer';

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($file);



        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)

                                ->setCellValue('A1','Employer Name')

                                ->setCellValue('B1','Emp ID')

                                ->setCellValue('C1','Designation')

                                ->setCellValue('D1','Zone')
                                ->setCellValue('E1','Password');



         $query = $this->session->userdata('employ');


        $query = preg_replace('/LIMIT.*/', '', $query);

        $res = $this->common_model->execute_query($query);

        $row = 2;

        foreach($res as $result)

        {


                        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)

                                ->setCellValue('A'.$row,$result->profile_name)

                                ->setCellValue('B'.$row,$result->profile_empid)

                                ->setCellValue('C'.$row,$result->profile_desig)

                                ->setCellValue('D'.$row,$result->profile_zone)
                                ->setCellValue('E'.$row,$result->profile_pass);



            $row++;

        }

        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Employer list'.date("Y-m-d").'.xls');

    }
```

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet

```
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

    //header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=report.xls');

    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed

    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');



    // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed

    header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past

    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified

    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1

    header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0



    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

    $objWriter->save('php://output');

    exit;
```

it gives an excel file with this content:
PK–jGG’D²Xð[Content_Types].xml­”MNÃ0…÷œ"ò%nY

Comment: if u view source of that controller i m getting "
ÐÏà¡±á����������������;��þÿ ��������������������������������þÿÿÿ���

Comment: code is correct its it something to do with meta utf ....

Comment: Solved model was having error......